# Nagios service returns null when using -T .cfg in command line

Tags: plugins, monitoring, nagios

I'm currently learning how to make scripts to create create plugins for the Nagios Framework. We have a script with a .cfg file for some default options.

So we've added a service and defined a command. For the command we wrote the following

```
command-line      filepath -T file.cfg
```

With filepath being the destination of the script and .cfg the template for it. Without the -T file.cfg option it works and returns the option which is hard coded in our script as status information. We want one of the options in the .cfg file so we really need to give the script access to it but at the moment when adding the '-T file.cfg' part the status information of the service return (null)

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

We had to define the path of the config path also

```
filepath/file.cfg
```